# Can't include Spreadsheet Excel Writer

Tags: php, excel, pear, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I have a problem with Pear package Spreadsheet Excel Writer. I want to generate excle file from php and found this package on internet.

I copied smaple code from official page, but it doesn't work. Of course I have the pear installed on my server(Deb7, apache2, php5). I try to find where the app is not work and found that it doesn't include a file.

```
include_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php'
```

I installed the package by the command:

```
pear install -f OLE
pear install -f Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer
```

I don't have any idea why that package doesn't include. I try including other packages and it forks fine. I inspected files in that package and recognized that Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Worksheet.php  may cause the problem(I included each file in package and only this can't get included).

Please help me, maybe you now other way to generate excel from php.

Comment: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: ok I used this, but how using this i can download by browser the generated xls?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your include path correctly before you can use the pear-installed files.

Follow the instructions in http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Don't forget to restart the web server after modifying `php.ini`.